# При нажатии на кнопку передать определенный тип и выполнить запрос в Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Как правильно делать такие вещи во Vue когда у меня есть три кнопки, при нажатии на одну из них мне нужно присвоить ordersType её тип а затем выполнить запрос исходя из того типа что в ordersType?
Index.vue

```
<button @click="ordersType = 'orders'">orders</button>
<button @click="ordersType = 'transactions'">transactions</button>
<button @click="ordersType = 'info'">reports</button>

data() {
  return {
    ordersType: 'order'
}
},
method() {
  makeFetch() {
    fetch(`${this.ordersType}`)...
}
}
```

Comment: Вариантов куча, но наверное лучше через `watch`, чтоб запрос не отправлялся при каждом клике на кнопку.

Comment: можете пожалуйста показать пример, я с Vue ещё не сильно нормально дружу

Comment: Изначально `ordersType` должен быть все таки `null`

Comment: а если передавать вот так это нормальная практика? @click="ordersType(orders)"

Comment: Да, так правильнее будет, если в шаблоне вы не будете ничего присваивать, а передадите параметр в функцию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, как-то вот так это может выглядеть.

```js
data() {
  return {

  }
},
methods: {
  makeFetch(type) {
    fetch(`url/${type}`)...
  }
}
```

```html
<button @click="makeFetch('orders')">orders</button>
<button @click="makeFetch('transactions')">transactions</button>
<button @click="makeFetch('info')">reports</button>
```

Comment: @РустамГимранов но кнопка нужна для того, чтобы запросы слать...